# MVC Validation input-validation-error CSS not working with the custom validation

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller, validation

MVC Validation "input-validation-error" CSS not working with the custom validation, any help please ?

Comment: check with firebug or similar tool if css is loaded properly on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another methodology to solve this problems
is to create my own attribute that inherits from the .net built-in Attribute
for more details please visit [This](http://mahaafifi.blogspot.com/2011/09/custom-validation.html)